# Do Fun Questions (example given) Have a Place Here?

Tags: discussion, scope, asking-questions

As an example from Retrocomputing SE: [Fun or interesting projects to do with Mac Classic II?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/1203/fun-or-interesting-projects-to-do-with-mac-classic-ii)
This is an upvoted opinion-based question with good answers, including an accepted one, all upvoted.

Why are these types of questions disallowed/discouraged here? Can we change that? Do we want to?

Comment: Fast forward to now, the linked question on Retrocomputing.SE has been deleted...

Answer (score 9):

I am answering as a user.
Other <del>triumviri</del> moderators may disagree.

If a question is related to Latin, well asked, sufficiently focused, answerable, and interesting, I will accept it to the site gladly.
The motivation can be idle curiosity, academic research, fun, or anything else.

Many questions are somewhat opinion-based, and that is fine.
For example, I would consider this opinion-based question very interesting: "If you had to demonstrate Cicero's prose style with one sentence from his works, what would it be and why? How does it reflect his style?"
It essentially asked "what is the most characteristic sentence Cicero wrote?" and answers are based on opinions, but the question also asks for an explanation.
I would much like to see well explained answers to this one!
(Since I like the example question so much, I [actually asked it at the main site](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/2121/79).)

I think opinion-based questions often work if the question is precise enough and others can reasonably answer.
An occasional fun question would be fun.

If you have such a question in mind, I suggest you give it a try.
It is then let for the community to decide whether it is good.
Voting on posts at the main site is the main mechanism for defining our scope.
After a couple of attempted fun questions we will know what we want.

Comment: Open-ended questions like this often make me nervous based on my experience on other sites, but realistically it seems unlikely that all the sudden our friendly environment would descend into a nasty battle over Cicero's best sentence.  And if it did, I think the community would notice and take action to put it to rest with new guidelines or practices.  So, +1.

Comment: @Nathaniel♦: Agreed! We can cross that bridge when we get it, or rather, *if*. (Indeed, if we should get to it, that would probably mean that we had grown big...)

Answer (score 1):

> Yes.

W. Shakespeare: *Hamlet*, [Act I, Scene 5, line 881](http://www.opensourceshakespeare.org/views/plays/play_view.php?WorkID=hamlet&Act=1&Scene=5&Scope=scene&LineHighlight=880#880).